# Volume of the ball by Archimedes method

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, measure-theory, analytic-geometry

If I have $B:=\{x\in \mathbb R^3 :||x||_2 \le r\}$ as a closed 3 dimensional ball of radius $r>0$, how can I show that the formula $\lambda^3=\frac4 3\pi r^3$ holds? I was given these figures to use:

the half-ball of radius $r$ is $H:=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb R^3:x^2+y^2+z^2\le r^2 \text{ and } z\ge 0\}$,
the cone standing on its peak of height $r$ with circle of radius $r$ as base:
$K:=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb R^3:x^2+y^2\le z^2 \text{ and } 0\le z\le r\}$
the cylinder of radius $r$ and height $r$: $Z:=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb R^3:x^2+y^2\le r^2 \text{ and } 0\le z\le r\}$

I honestly have no idea where or how to use them, or where to even begin with this, any help on this matter would be amazing!

Also I have an idea to use that Lebesgue-measure $\lambda^2 $ of the circle is $\pi r^2 $ but not really sure how to use it

Comment: See page 2: https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Ford/Apostol496-508.pdf

Comment: I still don't really get it, but it is quite helpful

Comment: Watch also https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=npG4MwDmDDc

Comment: @RobertZ What difference is between the normal proof of the volume formula and the addition $B:={x∈R^3:||x||2≤r}$? and how does the lambda^3 come into play???

Comment: I think that $\lambda^3$ means the $3$-dimensional Lebesgue measure of $B$ that is the volume of $B$. More precisely it should be written as $\int_B d\lambda^3$.
What is the source of your problem?

Comment: But how does that impact the proof? I've never been good at these. And it is just a random task I found to practice proofs.

Comment: This "random" task is: show that the "normal" formula $V=\frac4 3\pi r^3$ can be obtained knowing the volume of the cylinder and of the cone. This is explained in the video and in the article given above.

Comment: Ah, I think I needed to hear the problem put in simple terms, thank you!

Comment: This calls for the [Cavalieri's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cavalieri%27s_principle), as presented e.g. in this aplet in GeoGebra: [Cavalieri’s Principle and the Volume of a Sphere](https://www.geogebra.org/m/ZnfvtvJv).